# How to test React Native Typescript app COMPONENTS with jest?

Tags: typescript, react-native, ts-jest

I have been trying to start testing my React Native Typescript Components with jest for quite some time with no success. I have found a lot of examples /answers (including: [one source](https://kenjdavidson.com/writing/2020/11/02/react-native-typescript-jest), [another source](https://janhesters.com/using-typescript-with-react-native), [yet another link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript),  etc.) but none of them help.
Changing the setup to be as shown in example project [example](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Native-Starter/tree/master/ExampleProject) (with further link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709307/cannot-read-property-bindings-of-null-error-in-reactnative)) or another example project ([another example](https://github.com/jaywcjlove/react-native-typescript-example)) do not work.

With some setups I am able to run simple tests, but if I try to import a Component, I get the error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/XXX/node_modules/react-native-iphone-x-helper/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/components/BottomNavigation.tsx:13:1)
```

File contents:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
preset: 'react-native',
moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node']
```

}

package.json "jest"

```
  "jest": {
"preset": "react-native",
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",
  "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
},
"globals": {
  "ts-jest": {
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.jest.json"
  }
},
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "ts",
  "tsx",
  "js"
],
"testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$"
```

}

tsconfig.json

```
{"compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "allowJs": true,
      "jsx": "react-native",
      "noEmit": true, 
      "strict": true, 
      "noUnusedLocals": true,                      
      "noUnusedParameters": true,                 
      "noImplicitReturns": true,          
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,       
      "moduleResolution": "node",               
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true, 
      "skipLibCheck": true,                           
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        
    }, "include": [
        "src"
      ]}
```

Could someone point me to an example that works?

Answer (score 1):

Found an example setup that works:
[example with configurations that allow running tests](https://github.com/NewBieBR/typescript-react-native-starter).

I did leave the jest.setup.js-file out and also the line

```
 setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
```

in the jest.config.js file.